# Parsing html body outer text only

Tags: java, jsoup, html-parsing

I used JSoup to parse HTML.
How can I get ony the body text?
I mean I want only outer text without inculding others tag's text.

(Music causes us to think eloquently.)

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p class=\"mm3h\">ဂီတကဆွဲဆောင်အားကောင်းတဲ့ကျွန်တော်တို့ကိုဖြစ်စေတယ်လို့ထင်တယ်။</p> 
        Music causes us to think eloquently.
        <a class=\"\" href=\"\" aria-label=\"--Ralph Waldo Emerson (1 item)\">--Ralph Waldo Emerson</a>
    </body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<body> your content </body>");
String body = doc.body().textNodes().get(1).text();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I've already tried with this code. This _doc.body().text()_ parse all of the text between body tag. I just only want to get outer text. @RichardK

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @Mthk I've updated my answer. Now it's what you're looking for.

Comment: @RichardK Thank you. I got it. But the correct answer is _doc.body().textNodes().get(0).text();_ .

Answer (score 4):

I know the question is already answered and the answer is marked as the accepted answer, but I think there is another way to get what was asked:

JSoup offers the [`ownText()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#ownText--) method. with this, you can get all text nodes of an element that are direct children of the element. Child elements and their text nodes will not be returned.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<body> text <p> not included </p> included </body>");
Element body = doc.body();
String ownText = body.ownText();
```